# update oracle date column with different date values

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

When updating the old dates to the new dates, I am getting

> SQL Error: **ORA-00932**: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got CHAR
>   00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

```
UPDATE test
   SET date1 = 
   CASE date1
    WHEN '22-OCT-19' THEN '23-OCT-19'
    WHEN '21-OCT-19' THEN '22-OCT-19'
    WHEN '20-OCT-19' THEN '21-OCT-19'
    WHEN '17-OCT-19' THEN '18-OCT-19'
    WHEN '06-OCT-19' THEN '07-OCT-19'
    WHEN '05-OCT-19' THEN '06-OCT-19'
    WHEN '04-OCT-19' THEN '05-OCT-19'
    WHEN '03-OCT-19' THEN '04-OCT-19'
    WHEN '02-OCT-19' THEN '03-OCT-19'
    WHEN '29-SEP-19' THEN '30-SEP-19'
    WHEN '27-SEP-19' THEN '28-SEP-19'
   END;
```

Comment: Your current query will update all other dates not included in the CASE to NULL. You better use a WHERE-condition with those dates and then simply add 1 day.

Comment: @dnoeth I believe that by using my example in my answer OP will avoid that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message implies, you mix dates and varchars.

Your current query will update all other dates not included in the CASE to NULL. You better use a WHERE-condition with date literals and then simply add 1 day:

```
UPDATE test
SET date1 = date1 + 1
WHERE DATE1 IN
 ( DATE '2019-10-22'
  ,DATE '2019-10-21'
  ,DATE '2019-10-20'
  , etc.
 )
```

Comment: I think this will not work for this kind of data. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=280b193e6bb801006f18dd79fe104c7d

Comment: It fails because your inserted dates in the year 0019 instead of 2019, two-digit years are bad :-) see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=69d6f9263fba5155357d1dd2c3285b3b When you switch to Standard SQL *date literals* it's much shorter and there's no more need for `to_date` as there's only one format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: I have inserted dates as OP has in his question "WHEN '22-OCT-19' THEN '23-OCT-19"... I assumed that this is how OP has it in his table.

Answer (score 0):

Does phrasing the logic using explicit `DATE` literals fix the problem?

```
UPDATE test
    SET date1 = (CASE date1
                     WHEN DATE '2019-10-22' THEN DATE '2019-10-23'
                     WHEN DATE '2019-10-21' THEN DATE '2019-10-22'
                     . . .
                 END);
```

Comment: I have tried it and no success : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=347a23e42c6e50b465768e876d70d3ff

Comment: @VBokšić . . . There are no errors in the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I agree but it does not update the date : WHEN DATE '2019-10-22' THEN DATE '2019-10-23' ?

Comment: @VBokšić . . . You probably just need a `COMMIT` after the `UPDATE` -- which is hard to do in the Fiddle environments for Oracle.

Comment: My example did not need any commit and from that point of view I have commented your code and the code that is accepted from the OP. As you can see here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5d21a42a72649928f220e6ba59231644

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
update test 
set date1 = 
(
    case date1
       when to_date('22-OCT-19', 'dd-mon-yyyy') THEN to_date('23-OCT-19', 'dd-mon-yyyy')
       else date1
    end
);
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c74eae344530e7f25ee12f24197bc78f)